# How can i get the column value which corresponds to largest value in another?

Tags: sql

I have the following duplicates:

```
id  | product id | actv mnths | 
123 | ClassA     |   11       |
123 | ClassC     |   1        |
456 | ClassC     |   7        |
456 | ClassA     |   5        |
```

i would like to "dedupe" it by taking only those where actv mnths is highest so returning:

```
   id   | product id | actv mnths | 
    123 | ClassA     |   11       |
    456 | ClassC     |   7        |
```

How can i do this using SQL, and what abut cases where they are equal how would this be handled?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T.id,T.product_id,T.actv_mnths
FROM
(
   SELECT id,product_id,actv_mnths,
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY actv_mnths DESC)AS XCOL
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
)T WHERE T.XCOL=1
```

You can try to use ROW_NUMBER-functionality

Comment: If 2 rows both have the same maximum actv_mnths, this query will only retrieve one of them.  If you want ALL rows with the same maximum actv_mnths then use rank() instead of row_number.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't it be done even easier?

```
SELECT
    id,
    product_id,
    MAX(actv_mnths)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    id,
    product_id
```

Comment: This solution gets the max value for actv_months per each id & product_id, but not the row with the max value per id

Comment: Yes you're right didn't realize that there's different ProductIDs for the same ID